# what does it mean by (BYTE)-1

Tags: c++

I'm reading someone else's code:

```
#define     CPUTYPE_INVALID  ((BYTE)-1)
```

What does that mean? I guess it has the same effect as follows ,

```
#define     CPUTYPE_INVALID  255
```

if we already have

```
typedef unsigned char       BYTE; (in windef.h)
```

Comment: It depends on what `BYTE` is.

Comment: `BYTE` (and `char`) may have more than 8 bits.

Comment: But what if `#define BYTE 17`?  It all depends on the expansion of the `BYTE` macro.  </devil's advocate mode>

Comment: {Grin} "_someone else's code_" We have no context and little information to begin with.  I just threw that in there because you __cannot__ (always) infer usage or value from name.

Comment: @lornix `BYTE` actually looks more like a typedef than a macro for me!

Comment: Um, that was added later.  Oh well, it was fun while it lasted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(the following assumes BYTE being a type since you wrote it's in windef.h)**

Assuming `BYTE` = `char`, this yields `-1` since it's converting `-1` (integer) as a `char`. It's just a C-style cast for -1.

It's a way of getting "-1" in the system-defined `BYTE` type, either signed or unsigned (in that case it's the maximum representable). In the signed case, to indicate a bogus entry, it's a common practice to use a -1 value (or an extreme one when you have a limited number of entries)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#define BYTE char
#define CPUTYPE_INVALID  ((BYTE)-1)

#define BYTE2 unsigned char
#define CPUTYPE_INVALID2  ((BYTE2)-1)

int main() {
    cout << to_string(CPUTYPE_INVALID); // -1
    cout << to_string(CPUTYPE_INVALID2); // 255
    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/DGTkwq

Comment: May I know why the downvote? If I wrote something wrong I'd like to be corrected

Comment: I didn't downvote, but there's no need to guess; the OP has updated the question to show how `BYTE` is defined.

Answer (score 2):

It's a C-style cast.  Since `BYTE` is an unsigned type, equivalent to `unsigned char`, the expression `((BYTE)-1)` is equivalent to `UCHAR_MAX`, which most likely has the value `255`. (This is required by the rules for converting an out-of-range integer value to an unsigned type; the value is wrapped around so it's in range.)

It differs from just `255` in that (a) the intent is clearer, and (b) it guarantees that the expression is of type `BYTE`, whereas the constant `255` is of type `int`.

Comment: +1. Noteworthy, the promotion of (-1) to BYTE via the cast utilizes C99 6.3.1.3-p2 : "Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type.". In other words, the allowable range of `BYTE` being 0..255, repeatedly sum **256**, starting at -1, until the value falls in that range. As it turns out, it has to add only *once*. The result is 255 as a `BYTE`.

Comment: Anyway the same as the 2's complement of -1 considered as an unsigned

Comment: @MarcoA. Thanks for bringing that up. For some reason I thought this was a C question. Thanks for keeping me honest =) The relevant standard citing for C++ is in C++11 4.7p2 [conv.integral] : "If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the least unsigned integer congruent to the source integer (modulo 2n where n is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type). Note: In a two’s complement representation, this conversion is conceptual and there is no change in the bit pattern (if there is no truncation)."

Comment: @WhozCraig congratulations for that finding, I have to admit you're really passionate about C++ :) Glad I could help!